# Multiple Series/Categories Issue SSRS column chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts, categories, series

I need to group by the values (disturbed, reshape, etc) and then the series needs to be the TITLE. Basically need to swap the TITLE's and values. The data is correct but not grouped accordingly to the values.

```
 #                                        o
 # o                 o                  # o
 # o                 o                  # o
 # o               # o                  # o
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
TITLE_A          TITLE_B              TITLE_C
```

Legend:            # - Disturbed;           o - Reshaped

Thanks

Comment: can you post screnshot here if possible ?

Comment: Not to worry, I changed my SQL query and basically turned the table onto its side and specified the col's I wanted and then grouped by them.